# When hovered over the Foundation Jquery menu (without dropdowns) a white patch appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I used the Foundation top bar to create the menu. None of the elements have drop downs. But if I hover over an item it will leave behind a white patch like this :

[image]

This only happens in Google Chrome. When tried in Firefox it works fine! How to get rid of this patch?

Here's a link to the live website : http://secret-temple-3539.herokuapp.com/

The css file :

```
    @import "compass";
    $top-bar-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.2);

    body{
        font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive !important;
    }

    .top-bar-section{
        a{
            font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive !important;
            background: transparent !important;
            @include transition-property(all);
        @include transition-duration(0.3s);
        @include transition-timing-function(ease-in);

            &:hover{
                background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.2) !important;
                @include border-radius(50px);
                color: #ffffff !important;
            }
        }
    }

    .top-bar{
        z-index: 10 !important;
        -moz-animation-duration: 1.8s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1.8s;
        -o-animation-duration: 1.8s;
        -ms-animation-duration: 1.8s;
        animation-duration: 1.8s;

        li{
            background: transparent !important;
        }
    }

    #title{
        float: left;
        margin-left: -1000000000000000px;
    }

    #homeTop{
        height: 65%;
        background-image: image-url("leafyhomebg.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: -1 !important;
    }

    #home{
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: image-url("homebg.jpg");
    }

    .fixed-custom{
        position:fixed;
        z-index: 99;
        width:100%;
    }

    #leafLogo{
            display: block;
        height: 24%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 8%;
    }

    .hiMsg{
        color: #e9e9e9;
        font-size: 242%;
        font-size: 2vw;
        font-weight: 100;
        margin-top: 2%;
        text-align: center; 

        &.lineTwo{
            margin-top: -28px;
            margin-top: 2.8%;
        }

        .emTxt{
            color: #b3b3b3;
        }
    }

    .sImgCont{
        width: 20%;
        float: left;

        .sImg{
                border: 3px solid #ffffff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px #828282;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        opacity: 0.7 !important;
        width: 43%;
        }
    }

    .sImgWrap{
        margin-top: 1%;
    }
```

PS : I think its something to do with links... Go to the link again and refresh... see. I have added some links at the bottom and when we hover them, again a big patch appears!

Comment: It does not occur with my version chrome (linux mint)

Comment: Can't see the white patch (Chrome 35 on OSX) but the <li>'s turn completely grey on hover (I'm assuming this isn't intended?)

Comment: @arthur.sw Whats the distro? Im also in Chrome in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @AdamskiFTW Can you please send me a screenshot?

Comment: @AdamskiFTW I think I saw the issue you are talking about.. I tried in Windows! And no its not intended! What might be the problem?

Comment: Cinnamon v1.8.8, LinuxMint 15: olivia (x86-64)

Comment: @EApubs I can't seem to figure it out from the element inspector alone - there doesn't seem to be :hover states. Are you targeting the <li>'s with Javascript or anything? (Foundation top-bar is a nightmare to style).

Comment: @AdamskiFTW Yep, I also couldn't find anything from the inspector. No I didn't write any javascript my self. :-(

Comment: @EApubs Could it be one of your SASS variables in Foundation? Although saying that I can't see anything in the CSS referencing the background-color change :-/

Comment: @AdamskiFTW The only scss variable is $top-bar-color (I added my css in the question above). I even removed it and tried... still not working :-(

Comment: @EApubs Are you setting the background-color to transparent anywhere? You're better off setting it to none. I'm stumped with this one - almost certain it's to do with that transparency though.

Comment: @AdamskiFTW Set all to none. But still didn't work. I think its something to do with links... Go to the link again and refresh... see. I have added some links at the bottom and when we hover them, again a big patch appears!

Comment: @EApubs Seems to be the transition-duration adding it? Try taking out the transition effect?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. Its in this piece of code :

```
#title{
    float: left;
    margin-left: -1000000000000000px;
}
```

When I remove that float, everything came back to normal. So I replaced the float with this `position: fixed;` and now everything works fine!

Thank for everyone who tried to help!